# Using tapply on data with counts to add zeros and NAs

Tags: r, database, tapply

I have a DB composed of: Species ID (as factor), counts, site, visit, year. Find a subset in here [[Google Drive]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2-0MCzdmx4pWW9xQzNLNnRaRzQ/view?usp=sharing)

I want to create a 4D array with the dimensions: species, site, visit and year. Counts as cell values. For which I am using the following code:

```
y<-tapply(counts,list(species,site,visit,year), sum)
```

Some sites were not always visited within and along the years. Therefore obtaining NAs in the cell, which actually is fine. My problem is when some sites were visited at a given visit and year but the species was not seen. The original DB only has the counts were seen (except few exceptions). Therefore the code gives a NA value to those cells, but I want a 0- value.

Anyone has any advise on how to add these 0-value cells when the site was visited but the species was not seen, while keeping NAs for when sites were not visited?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your data in the question as links can break or change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data is in `data.frame` df

```
library(reshape2)

tmp <- dcast(df, site + visit + year ~ species, value.var = 'counts', fill = 0)
df <- melt(tmp, id.vars = c('site', 'visit', 'year'), variable.name = 'species', value.name = 'counts')
y <- tapply(df$counts, list(df$species, df$site, df$visit, df$year), sum)
```

Comment: Thanks you danas! It works. I only added the function sum to the dcast so to have the sum of observations when value is not zero.

tmp  <- dcast(df, site + visit + year ~ species, sum,value.var = "counts", fill = 0)